# Média de colunas da matriz

Tags: c, matriz

[image: Questão]

O código esta com erro em imprimir a média e preencher a segunda matriz.

O código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   float matriz[3][6];
   float SomaImp = 0, SomaDQ = 0, SomaPS = 0;
    
    //preenchendo matriz
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            matriz[r][l] = (rand() % 257)/10;
        }
    }
    
    //Exibindo matriz
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            printf("%.2f      ", matriz[r][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //Somando as colunas impares
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            if((l%2!=0)&&(l!=0))
            {
                SomaImp += matriz[r][l];
            }
        }
    }
    
    //media da 2a e 4a colunas
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            if((l==1)&&(l==3))
            {
                SomaDQ += matriz[r][l];    
            }
        }
    }
    
    //alterando os valores da 6a colunas
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            if((l==0)&&(l==1))
            {
                SomaPS += matriz[r][l];   
            }
        }
        matriz[r][5] = SomaPS;
    }
    
    printf("\nSoma das coluna impares %.2f, Média das colunas 2 e 4 %.2f\n\n", 
    SomaImp, SomaDQ);
    printf("Esta é a matriz alterada\n");
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++)
        {
            printf("%.2f      ", matriz[r][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((l==1)&&(l==3))` esse `if` está errado, é impossível a variável "l" ser igual a 1 e 3 ao mesmo tempo, assim como esse outro if `if((l==0)&&(l==1))`

Comment: Que erro bobo rs, tinha modificado um if e esqueci o outro. Mudei os dois e funcionou, obrigado pela a ajuda.